# Are there NDE known where Buddha is met?

Tags: the-buddha

It happens to people when they get for example a heart attack they will get a near death experience (NDE). Sometimes they encounter a very bright light but sometimes persons like Jesus encounters them. Probably such experiences are very cultural influenced but are there studies of NDE in more Buddhist countries where Buddha appears in a NDE?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. I know some people encounter Lord Yama in their NDE but not Buddha. Maybe because Buddha has attained parinibbana.

Answer (score 0):

The NDE is one and the same phenomena as the OBE (out of body experience) this is described by the Buddha as manomaya, or 'mind made body' and is expressed as a fruit of the contemplative life. One is able to leave body at will after the fourth jhana and as one develops the mind in the immaterial realms. This happens most often during sleep when the jhanas have been attained regularly. This is also known as astral plaining. The NDE is exactly this, this mind leaves the body in an astral body. Death, astral plaining and deep meditation are one and the same thing. I know a person who astral travels regularly and she has stated that she has met the Buddha. Even though his spirit has been liberated into Nibbana, she explains that a fragment of his consciousness still remains that continues to teach in the higher realms.

Comment: Interesting. How, in which way, did she recognice the Buddha as Buddha, Avi Samvadi.

Comment: Good question. She described a golden city, or 'temple of temples' which resides in the upper regions of the physical heavens, or devas realms. Here many spiritual teachers teach the path and people visit to practice. This corroborated my own experience of this city in personal visions. She did not describe what he looked like, however I get the feeling, if the Buddha spoke to you, you would know you were speaking to the Buddha.

Comment: Another spiritual friend/teacher of mine who has not met this lady also details meeting many spiritual teachers who have long left this plane and they both describe this as a normal part of one's spiritual journey and mastery over the immaterial jhanas and OBE. I personally pop into the surrounding forests of this city front time to time, but I am not disciplined in the OBE enough just yet to maintain it enough to make it through to the city. I may or may not achieve this. and it is not my goal. This is for those interested in traversing the immaterial realms and OBE.

Comment: Also bare in mind, at this point one is in manomayao, and not bound by the physical body and senses. When you meet someone, there is a lot more going on than just physically seeing someone. He may even project a recognisable image of himself to the people surrounding him who are there to listen, but this is speculation. If scepticism arises upon reading this, I would direct you the Buddha's teaching on 'a handful of leaves'.

Comment: @user12001 Since a death is not followed by return to a same physical body and NDE and/or 'an astral projection' usually are, these phenomena differ by result. Because they differ by result, they are also different by their causes and/or processes, that means, that they also differ by natures, which means they are not the same.

Comment: @user12001 Also, 'manomaya' may refer to a Hinduism term based on an idea of Atman, which contradicts one of the core principles of Dharma (Anatman) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchakosha